# Getting all vertex (lat, long) points every 1 meter between two known points?

Tags: c#, algorithm, gps, gis

I am currently using C# to try and write code that will take a start point and end point latitude and longitude coordinate pair in decimal value and show the GPS points(latitude and longitude) between these two points(start and end point) in my database.

For example:

I have start coordinates of latitude 39.90732 and longitude 116.45353 and I have an endpoint of latitude 39.90736 and longitude 116.44927. Query and show the GPS points(latitude and longitude value) between these two points in my database on datagridview or listview.

Also count number of GPS point on every 1 meter interval.

[1. image description for first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4pAJ.jpg)

[2. image description for second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Oat.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? You want someone to write the code for you? If you write c# code, why the java tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a set of coordinates in your database and want to get the ones which lie on a certain line?

For your first problem: To be mathematically correct, you would have to get the equation `f(x)= k * x + d` for that line and check your points, whether they are a valid solution for that equation. You can skip checking points which definitely are outside the rectangle spanned by your start point `(s_x, s_y)` and end point `(e_x, e_y)`. Ie you only need to check points `(x, y)` where `x` is between `s_x` and `e_x` and `y` is between `s_y` and `e_y`.

For your second problem: If you have a set of valid points derived from problem 1, it should be quite easy to calculate the distance to the start point for each of them and then group them by the distance.

All of this assumes, you know how to convert your gps coordinates into the metric system and your distances are short enough that the projection of the spheric earth on a flat surface can be neglected. For instance, the distance between two longitudes is maximum at the equator and gets smaller towards the poles. Furthermore the shortest distance between two points on the globe may not be what it seems to be on a flat map using the Mercator projection.

Comment: exactly ! what i am looking for !!